# What specifies placeholder alignment of the UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have an App in two languages Arabic and English,

When flipping the UI using:

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
//And/Or:
UITextField.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

The placeholders of the textFields stays the same, I understand that the `semanticContentAttribute` only flips the Trailing and leading constraints.

What if I want to change the alignment of the placeholders of the textfields, with changing the semantics of the view?

Note that:

I have tried changing the `textAlignment` of the `UITextField` to all the possible values.

Comment: I think it will be changed automatically when your system language is Arabic in your iPhone.

Comment: No Nadia, I have tried this and it did not work as well.

Comment: what happened when you tried changing the textAlignment property ?

Answer (score 2):

So try to do 2 things.

1. to add arabic to your project (click + under localisations section)
   [image]
2. choose the last option in the alignment field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**`textAlignment`** property specifies placeholder text alignment of a UITextField object.

Comment: It says in the question: *I have tried changing the `textAlignment` of the `UITextField` to all the possible values.*